# VS2015 debug ASP.NET step over jumps to site.master

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I recently started working on a C# ASP.NET solution built in VS2012 Pro in VS2015 Community edition.

When I am debugging the app in VS2012, all is fine.
However, when I have a breakpoint set in the C# code and step-over in the VS2015 IDE, it always plops me straight into the Site.Master .apsx code, and I cannot step through the code behind where I have the breakpoint set ?

I am sure there is probably a debug setting I am missing or forgetting but can't figure it out yet.

Does anyone have any ideas ?
Thanks for any input.

some details.

The breakpoint stops where expected, in the C# code behind like so;

```
private int ImportProjects(string _importFilename, oCompany selectedCompany) {
int rec_count = 0;
<breakpoint here> string fname = _importFilename;
...
```

When I Step Over (F10) it opens up Site.Master aspx code (not .cs)
and steps to the following lines in the aspx code:

```
[steps to here] <title><%: Page.Title %> CPP Portal</title>   5207ms elpased

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">     
    [steps to here] <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>  525ms elapsed

<footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            [steps to here] <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> CPP Tools</p>
```

the initial breakpoint is in a function called from an onclick event

in the web.config I have

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Comment: What about F11? What does that do?

Comment: same result on Step Into (F11).

Comment: The other odd thing is that when trying to set breakpoint on some other lines (to see if any different) I am getting messages about "breakpoint failed to bind"

Comment: Hm. Possibly try to clean your solution and then rebuild?

Comment: ok - I found a solution here on Stackoverflow - related but only after I started getting the breakpoint binding errors:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944/breakpoint-failed-to-bind-visual-studio-2015   - need to force build in DEBUG - it was in RELEASE

Comment: Good! If you want to edit your question or post it as an answer, it would be great to help everyone else who may run into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here on Stackoverflow - after I started getting the breakpoint binding errors: 
[Breakpoint Failed to Bind - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944/)

THe Solution was in RELEASE when I started working on it in the new VS2015 IDE - need to force build in DEBUG