# Visual Studio 2015 Debug and Release not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Building in Debug gives me a Release build; I can't get back to Debug. Consequently I had this problem which I solved by unclicking "Optimize code" in project properties: [Breakpoint Failed to Bind - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944/breakpoint-failed-to-bind-visual-studio-2015)

But the root cause seems to be that I'm stuck in Release. I confirmed it with this:

```
#if DEBUG
    stuff
#else
    other stuff
#endif
```

And also in Project Properties in the Build tab it always says Active (Release). How do I fix this?

Comment: Change the Active configuration under the Build / Config Manager menu.

Comment: Thank you! Also for some reason in the Configuration Manager under Debug the configuration for each project was set to Release. It should have been Debug.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dxiv said, you can change to Active configuration under Build, Config Manager, but in my case even though Debug was selected, Visual Studio had glitched somewhere and the configuration for each individual project was set to Release. Weird. I changed them back to Debug. Problem solved.