# Visual studio debugging for MVC only hit breakpoints once - Symbols not loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on ASP.NET Core 1.1 application and have big issue with debugging. it was working fine until recently only work when I create new project and it hit breakpoints in controller class but once application close and re-open it doesn't hit debugging point, although it still hit debugging point for startup.cs.

I believe it is complaining that symbols not been loaded as to test, I have created MVC 5 application and during debugging, the debugging red mark goes yellow, giving me symbols not loaded error message.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3

Really need help here if someone know the answer

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a screen shot about which line code you add the breakpoint? Please enable the symbols Server under Tools->Options->Debugging. One important issue is that whether the code was really called, please clean and rebuild the whole solution before you debug it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging not hit breakpoints in .NET CORE MVC 6 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628445/debugging-not-hit-breakpoints-in-net-core-mvc-6-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the same issue as this one? toxic.

[Debugging not hit breakpoints in .NET CORE MVC 6 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628445/debugging-not-hit-breakpoints-in-net-core-mvc-6-application/40691268#40691268)

If you disable the "Enable Just My Code", and Enable/disable the Microsoft symbols Server under TOOLs->Options->Debugging->Symbols, and then debug your app after you re-open it, how about the result? Or one possible reason is that the symbols loaded slowly(It is slow in my side if I repro it).