# Rider EAP And Visual Studio For Mac debug

Tags: debugging, rider

i try to debug my web app. When i add break point in gutter for proper line, i receive an error says : **The breakpoint cound not yet be bound to valid location**. What should i do to fix it?

Comment: Do not have an answer, but will say it is pretty common. if it were me I would start by doing a search on that error message. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944/breakpoint-failed-to-bind-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 1):

Rider debugging has been hosed on Mac for a few months now. Team is hard at work at fixing it - but it requires building out their own debugger or something of the such (yowch!)

See progress blog post here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/02/23/rider-eap-18-coreclr-debugging-back-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on an Android Xamarin project.
Problem was that I was changing the file after starting the debug session.
If I leave the file alone the debug breakpoints work fine.
Here's the issue I created:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-7118