# Visual Studio not hitting breakpoints that should always be hit + problems binding breakpoints in running code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

So I'm trying to add some new code to a project I'm working on, but Visual studio is not cooperating at all.

The project is only hitting breakpoints on code that existed prior to this set of changes. See the screenshot below, where the top and bottom breakpoints are pre-existing code, and some new code is inside the if statement.

I have no idea where to start, I've tried a clean and rebuild, to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling in Debug mode? Did you turn on the "Optimize Code" option by accident?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breakpoint Failed to Bind - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944/breakpoint-failed-to-bind-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No I didn't solve this. Yes I'm in Debug Mode.

The settings to this project haven't changed in a year, I've been doing all kinds of work on the project since then with no problems. 

The only thing that chaged was that this drive and OS was moved to a new physical machine.

Comment: I'm getting the 'Just My Code' warning on launch too, but that's clearly not the case, since I'm working on my own code.

Comment: Okay solved:

Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Suppress JIT optimization on module load

Comment: @RonBeyer - It was your idea, post the fix below and I'll score you some stack-points.

Comment: @ScubaSteve Go ahead and post it yourself, I hit my rep cap today anyway.

Comment: Haha okay, thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

Debug Menu -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Uncheck Suppress JIT optimization on module load

I'm not sure why it decided to start acting up now(haven't had this problem for a year of work on this project), but I'm guessing the code I'm trying to debug was optimized away.

Comment: If you had to uncheck the suppression of optimization in order for it to work then wouldn’t that mean the code NOW is being JIT optimized?

Comment: Yeah I guess it would. I had my thinking backwards. Well this problem makes even less sense now! I wonder what about suppressing JIT optimization causes breakpoints not to be hit... maybe it's a bug..

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a Rebuild All. (I see you tried that--I listed for others to consider.)
2. Make sure all dependencies for the code in question are current. You might have a project reference to an assembly (DLL) that has since fallen out of sync with its PDB/source code. Be sure all references point to currently compiled code.
3. I've sometimes seen this happen and an exit/restart of Visual Studio (all instances, just to be safe) works.

If any of these ideas work, please let us know which one did.

Comment: 1. I've done a rebuild all, no luck

2. Dependencies haven't changed. I'm the sole developer.

3. I've tried this, it was like the first thing I did. Including a computer restart.

Comment: Based on what you wrote, find the .pdb file for the assembly in question (i.e., the one on which you cannot set the breakpoint) and manually delete it. I say that to ensure that nothing is holding a lock on the pdb, preventing it from getting updated on a rebuild. Also, as crazy as this sounds, UNSET then set the breakpoint again--maybe even twice. I have seen cases where the error appears but then disappears on a subsequent attempt to set the breakpoint, and I can't figure out when/why that happens. I use VS 2017 Enterprise latest version.

Comment: That's pretty wild. I even switched versions of VS and created a brand new build from the remote. The JIT thing did the trick, can't explain why though.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue, tried everything above and the solution for me was to do: Debug > Delete all breakpoints to start fresh.